# Custom Jquery plugin auto advance bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to add auto advance to a jquery plugin I made myself. The slider has *next and previous buttons*.

I have created a *click simulation* function

```
  var autoAdvance = function(){
    $('#next').trigger('click');
  };
```

I want the autoAdvance function to *fire if auto is set to true* and stop if the **controls** (next and previous buttons) are clicked. This part - **stopping the auto advance** - does not work

```
  if(settings.auto === true){
    setInterval(autoAdvance, settings.pause);
    // Stop auto advance if controls are clicked 
    $('.controlls a').on('click', function(){
      clearInterval(autoAdvance);  
    });
  };
```

Where am I wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution I came up with for *simulating a click* on the 'Next' button every n milliseconds and stopping the auto-advance if a *real* click occurs:

```
  // Auto advance
  if(settings.auto === true){

    var autoAdvanceInterval = null;

    $(window).load(function(){
      autoAdvanceInterval = setInterval(function(){
        $('#next').trigger('click');  
      }, settings.pause);
      // When a control or dot is clicked by user
      // stop autoadvance by clearInterval method 
      $('.controls a,.bullets li').click( function(event) {
        if (event.originalEvent !== undefined) {
          clearInterval(autoAdvanceInterval);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var interval;
if(settings.auto === true){
   interval = setInterval(autoAdvance, settings.pause);
   // Stop auto advance if controls are clicked 
   $('.controlls a').on('click', function(){
     clearInterval(interval);  
   });
};
```

Would be perfect if you can create some jsFiddle to check it, but anyway try with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval part should look like this

```
settings.intervalHandler = setInterval(autoAdvance, settings.pause);
...
clearInterval(settings.intervalHandler);
```

And - maybe

- controlls - possible typo?
- if the code runs more than once, settings.auto is still true

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  var autoInterval = null;
  var settings ={};
  settings.auto = true;
  settings.pause = 2000; //3 sec
  $('.message span').fadeOut();
  
  var autoAdvance = function(){
    $('.next').data("auto", true);
    $('.next').trigger('click');
  };
  
  
  autoInterval = setInterval(autoAdvance, 5000);
    // Stop auto advance if controls are clicked 
  $('.next').on('click', function(){
    
    $('.message span').fadeIn(400).delay( 1000 ).fadeOut(400);
    var isAuto = $('.next').data("auto");
    if(isAuto !==true){
      clearInterval(autoInterval);
      $('.message span').fadeIn();
    }
    
    $('.next').data("auto",false);
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.message{
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message"><span>clicked</span></div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: can i get the explanation for down vote...? I am curious.

Comment: This script needs to make the distinction between a real click and a simulated one. Otherwise, the auto advance will stop after one slide. And it does.

Comment: Please have a look at this code snippet. This is not a complete solution but you can refer to it to take an idea. Here we are putting custom flag in `$.data` and using it to distinguish between auto click and manual click. Hope it will help you a bit.